# Lexer error with regex pattern

Tags: angularjs

When attempting to use the following regex pattern with ng-pattern:

`[(?=^.{8,100}$)((?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\W)|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d)).*$]`

angular js throws a lexer error:  Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 34-34 [] in expression

How do you escape the offending character which I believe is the backslash ().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. I was simply leaving the "/" out of the pattern in the attribute. First question is a bad question.

Comment: You helped me figure out why i was getting an error! So you've done well ;)
Now to figure out why my ng-repeat is negated. Regardless, thanks.

Comment: Had the same problem, was driving me crazy. Not such a bad question 'cause searching turned up this and solved my problem.